# Filter out duplicate rows in SQL Query

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, select, greatest-n-per-group

I am attempting to pull update compliance data from SCCM using SQL and have come up with the following query:

```
SELECT updates.ArticleID, updates.Title, devices.Name, MAX(compliance.LastStatusChangeTime) AS LastUpdated, compliance.[Status]
FROM v_UpdateDeploymentSummary deployments
INNER JOIN v_UpdateInfo updates
    ON deployments.CI_ID=updates.CI_ID
INNER JOIN CollectionMembers devices
    ON deployments.CollectionID=devices.SiteID
INNER JOIN v_UpdateComplianceStatus compliance
    ON compliance.CI_ID=deployments.CI_ID
WHERE compliance.[Status] IS NOT NULL
GROUP BY updates.ArticleID, updates.Title, devices.Name, compliance.[Status]
ORDER BY ArticleID, LastUpdated DESC
```

However, it looks like SCCM stores multiple compliance status records for the same update deployment. For example, **KB890830** was installed on that device last night, which is reflected in the row below from 09:19 this morning. I would like to change the query so that the only row returned is row 15 showing the latest status update for that KB.

[image]

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of aggregating, you could use window function `row_number()` for filtering:

```
SELECT *
FROM (
    SELECT 
        updates.ArticleID, 
        updates.Title, 
        devices.Name, 
        compliance.LastStatusChangeTime AS LastUpdated, 
        compliance.[Status],
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER(
            PARTITION BY updates.ArticleID 
            ORDER BY compliance.LastStatusChangeTime DESC
        ) rn
    FROM v_UpdateDeploymentSummary deployments
    INNER JOIN v_UpdateInfo updates
        ON deployments.CI_ID=updates.CI_ID
    INNER JOIN CollectionMembers devices
        ON deployments.CollectionID=devices.SiteID
    INNER JOIN v_UpdateComplianceStatus compliance
        ON compliance.CI_ID=deployments.CI_ID
    WHERE compliance.[Status] IS NOT NULL
) t
WHERE rn = 1
ORDER BY ArticleID, LastUpdated DESC
```

In the inner query, `row_number()` assigns ranks to records having the same `ArticleID`, ordered by descending `LastStatusChangeTime`. Then, the outer query filters on the top record in each group.